# aws elb and kubernetes certificate conflict

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb

Is it mandatory to have same certificate for kube api server and aws elb ? I changed the server key in kube-proxy config map with aws elb url. After that in master node, journalctl -xe gives an error from kubelet component stating certificate is not valid. If I replace the server back to masters ip it works again.

Version is 1.9.3

I have mapped aws elb's 443 port to redirect to api server's 6443 port.

regards
Achuth

Comment: It's mildly unclear from the question, but does the ELB's cert have the same SubjectAlternateName (SAN) list as does the API's cert? Also, normally kubernetes uses certs for authentication, too, so performing TLS termination at the ELB is unlikely to end well. A TCP ELB, or the new NetworkLB is far more likely to be helpful in your situation (but still, AFAIK, one needs to be cognizant of the SAN list in the cert)

Comment: Nope, it of 2 different SANs. EC2 gives a random name.